# R markdown - output based on predefined texts and loop in dataframe

Tags: r, r-markdown

What is the easiest way to create Word document in a loop? I'm fairly new to R-markdown and working with texts in R, so I'm hoping there is easy way to do below:

I have a dataset with users and for each of them I have to create separate page/document.
e.g. users:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Amy", "Bob", "Chloe", "Dan"),  
                 age = c(20, 35, 26, 41),  
                 country = c("USA", "UK", "FR", "AU"))
```

I have also pre-defined texts:

```
text <- c("Name: ",
          "Age: ",
          "Country: ")
```

I wonder if there is any easy way to loop through Names (rows) in df to produce Word page (not in table) per each person like below:

> Name: Amy
> Age: 20
> Country: USA

I've tried using R markdown solution like here [Use loop to generate section of text in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674824/use-loop-to-generate-section-of-text-in-rmarkdown) and it works until I add officer library (don't know why it doesnt work on my pc no mater what), so I've tried something like below:

```
for (i in seq(nrow(df))){
current <- df[i,]
current_value <- c(current$name,current$age, current$country)
df_text <- data.frame(text, current_value)
cat("\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```

but the output is in one line, there is df_text header and row numbers. I want later to work on text formatting so I wonder if there is an easy way to do this? (the real data may by up to 100 docx pages/files).

Answer (score 0):

## Files

### 1. `configure.R`

```
## @knitr configure

# --- Be very, very, very quiet loading these packages...
suppressPackageStartupMessages( suppressWarnings( require( purrr     )))
suppressPackageStartupMessages( suppressWarnings( require( rmarkdown )))

# --- Convenience function to create templates
to_file <- function( filespec, what ){
  connection <- file(
      description = filespec
    , open = "wt"
  )
  write( what, connection )
  close( connection )
}
```

### 2. `print_asis.R`

This is for the MS-Word pagebreak.

```
# Reference:
#  11.17 Customize the printing of objects in chunks (*)
#  https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html#opts-render

# Three elements are needed in order to print something ** as is **
# within a chunk (when everything else is formatted by knitr):

# NOTE the following:
# 1. `knit_print`, `knitr` and `asis_output` are all defined in the `knitr` package,
#    so don't mess with them.
# 2. `PRINT_ASIS`, `CONTROL`, and `FORMFEED` can be whatever you want them to be,
#    just remember, if you change them to something else, you make those changes
#    everywhere they appear.

## @knitr print_as_is

# --- (1) Define a `knit_print` method
PRINT_ASIS <- function( x, ... ){
  knitr::asis_output( x )
}

# --- (2) Register the method defined above
registerS3method(
    genname = "knit_print"                 # Generic name
  , class   = "CONTROL"                    # For which class of object?
  , method  = PRINT_ASIS                   # The custom method for this class
  , envir   = asNamespace( "knitr" )
)

# --- (3) Set the class of whatever is to be printed
FORMFEED <- '\\newpage'
class( FORMFEED ) <- "CONTROL"
```

### 3. `data.csv`

```
Name,Age,Country
Amy,20,USA
Bob,35,UK
Chloe,26,FR
Dan,41,AU
```

### 4. `Multipage_MSWord_Doc.Rmd`

The contents of this file are described in five pieces (a YAML header, plus four chunks) below:

## How it works

The **RMarkdown** template,
`Multipage_MSWord_Doc.Rmd`
takes input from the
`CONFIG_FILE` and the `DATA_FILE`,
then creates a `PAGE_TEMPLATE` and a `BODY_TEMPLATE`.

The `PAGE_TEMPLATE` uses the headings from the `DATA_FILE`, so feel free to add fields or change the names of the fields.

### The YAML header

Note that **you must edit the PATH** in the header, to point to the directory where you have saved the data and configuration files.

```
---
output: word_document
params:
  PATH:          'path/to/your/MultipageDoc'    # <------- EDIT THIS
  CONFIG_FILE:   'configure.R'
  DATA_FILE:     'data.csv'
  PAGE_TEMPLATE: 'AUTOGENERATED_page_template.R'
  BODY_TEMPLATE: 'AUTOGENERATED_body_template.R'
---
```

### The first chunk

The first chunk locates all the files and reads the input data

````
```{r STEP1_CONFIGURE, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}
# --- Use these labels to refer to the various files
CONFIG_FILE    <- file.path( params$PATH, params$CONFIG_FILE    )
PAGE_TEMPLATE  <- file.path( params$PATH, params$PAGE_TEMPLATE  )
BODY_TEMPLATE  <- file.path( params$PATH, params$BODY_TEMPLATE  )
DATA_FILE      <- file.path( params$PATH, params$DATA_FILE  )

# --- Get the special sauce that prints MS-Word pagebreaks
knitr::read_chunk( 'print_asis.R'     )

# --- The configuration file must exist
stopifnot( file.exists( CONFIG_FILE   ))
knitr::read_chunk( CONFIG_FILE )

# --- The data file must exist
stopifnot( file.exists( DATA_FILE   ))
THE_DATA <- read.csv( DATA_FILE)
i <- 0    # Initialize the record/page counter
```
````

### The second chunk

The second chunk generates the `PAGE_TEMPLATE`, which controls which data are on the page and how the data are formatted.

````
```{r STEP2_PAGE_TEMPLATE, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}

# --- Evaluate the <<configure>> chunk

<<configure>>

# --- Find out what this chunk is called and what the .Rmd file name is, as well
#     so we can put a comment in the templates that we generate. This way,
#     when you want to change a template, you can see where to find the code that
#     made it.

THIS_CHUNK <- knitr::opts_current$get()$label
THIS_FILE  <- knitr::current_input()

# --- Define the page template

stuff_to_put_in_page_template <- list(
    chunk_start = "## @knitr page_template\n"
  , counter = 'i <- 1 + i'
  , data = names( THE_DATA ) %>%
      purrr::map_chr(
        ~sprintf(
            "cat( sprintf( '%s: %%s', THE_DATA[ i, '%s' ] ))"
          ,                 .x
          ,                                         .x
         )
      )
  , notice = sprintf(
       "\n# NOTE: This file is generated by %s of %s\n#       Do not edit manually!\n"
     ,                              THIS_CHUNK
     ,                                     THIS_FILE
    )
)
stuff_to_put_in_page_template <- unlist( stuff_to_put_in_page_template )

# --- Write the page template to disk
to_file( PAGE_TEMPLATE, stuff_to_put_in_page_template )

# --- Make sure it gets there
stopifnot( file.exists( PAGE_TEMPLATE ))

# --- Now read it back as a chunk
knitr::read_chunk( PAGE_TEMPLATE )
```
````

### The third chunk

The third chunk generates the `BODY_TEMPLATE`, which glues the PAGEs together with a FORMFEED.

````
```{r STEP3_BODY_TEMPLATE, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}

# --- Find out what this chunk is called
#     so we can put a comment in the templates that we generate. This way,
#     when you want to change a template, you can see where to find the code that
#     made it.

THIS_CHUNK <- knitr::opts_current$get()$label

# --- Glue the pages together with form feeds
first_item    <- "<<page_template>>"
repeated_part <- "FORMFEED\n<<page_template>>"

# --- Define the body template

stuff_to_put_in_contents_chunk <- list(
    chunk_start = "## @knitr contents\n"
  , data = c( first_item, rep( repeated_part, nrow( THE_DATA ) - 1 ))
  , notice = sprintf(
       "\n# NOTE: This file is generated by %s of %s\n#       Do not edit manually!\n"
     ,                              THIS_CHUNK
     ,                                     THIS_FILE
    )
)
stuff_to_put_in_contents_chunk <- unlist( stuff_to_put_in_contents_chunk )

# --- Write the body template to disk
to_file( BODY_TEMPLATE, stuff_to_put_in_contents_chunk )

# --- Make sure it gets there
stopifnot( file.exists( BODY_TEMPLATE ))

# --- Now read it back as a chunk
knitr::read_chunk( BODY_TEMPLATE )

# --- Evaluate the <<print_as_is>> chunk
<<print_as_is>>
```
````

### The fourth chunk

The fourth chunk generates the puts it all together, and renders the multipage document.
Note that this chunk uses the `comment` option, as in `comment=''`. This is to over-ride the default formatting, which puts two pound-signs at the beginning of each line of output.

````
```{r STEP4_RENDER_DOCUMENT, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,comment=''}
# ,comment='' to prevent default ## at the beginning of each line of output

# --- Evaluate the <<contents>> chunk, populating the body of the multipage document.

<<contents>>
```
````

## Chunk names

Wherever you see `## @knitr` *something*,
this is the name of a *chunk* -- that is, a way to reference everything that follows
(until the next chunk, anyway)

Wherever you see `<<something>>`, the chunk called `something` is being referenced.

## Invoke from command-line

Invoke knitr from the command line using
`Rscript -e rmarkdown::render"('Multipage_MSWord_Doc.Rmd',output_file = 'Multipage.doc')"`